# Catch method taking long time to execute

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In selenium automation i'm checking for element displaying status by using below code

```
public boolean isDisplayed(String xpath){
try{
return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).isDisplayed();
}catch (Exception e){
return false;
}
```

}

but the issue is, if the element is not displaying it will go to catch statement and it takes more time to execute catch statement. How to make it fast this. Could you please help me here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

At first, try to wait for the availability of element using explicit wait and then check isDisplayed attribute:
the reason for waiting is implicit waiting for element because when the element is not interactable it waits to element or waiting time is reached.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, timeSpan);            wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.xpath(xpath)));
try{
return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).isDisplayed();
}
catch (Exception e){
return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, for some business flow i'm looking for false condition, to execute catch block its taking more time due to this time is consuming more. I feel your code will take more time to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `.findElements`, it will return number of the elements.

```
public boolean isDisplayed(String xpath){
    if(driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)).size()>0) {
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).isDisplayed();
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If `size>0` it will return first element is display.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but findElements() method is also taking more time if the element is not available. The execution time will be same as try catch block. Could you please help me if there are any other ways to do it fastly. Thanks